# Parsing this JSON data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, youtube

We have a working PHP function that grabs specific YouTube video information using YouTube API v3.

We're trying to use JavaScript (jQuery) to do the same thing. The issue is that using our PHP function causes the page to load very slowly while it's retrieving the data. We're hoping that using JavaScript will allow our page to load before (or during) the data requests from YouTube.

First of all, this is an example url for one of our videos (you will need an API key to see the returned information yourself):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=ce5KbCTfHoA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

That specific url will return this information:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/qRFx1vTFF-k7dkRzNB5rGQ-dqiQ\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/2yn7rCfXCu0o-GNVtMEQqYssSpE\"",
   "id": "ce5KbCTfHoA",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "33169",
    "likeCount": "281",
    "dislikeCount": "3",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "85"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

We are trying to retrieve the likeCount and dislikeCount of this video using JavaScript.

We can achieve this using PHP in the following manner:

```
function getVideoRatings() {
    $JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}");
    $json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);

    $likes = $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount'];
    $dislikes = $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['dislikeCount'];

    /* some other code... */
}
```

This successfully parses the json information returned by google and returns the likes (likeCount) and dislikes (dislikeCount) for the video.

We'd like to do this using JavaScript (jQuery). Can anyone please help me figure this out?

I really appreciate any help or bump in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: use AJAX to retrieve from server then pass it in client.

Comment: So I understand ajax to be an awesome way of doing this. However, after several days of trying to get ajax to work, I have given up. If you can post a snippet for me at least, that would help so much. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Reading through the tutorial you linked. Thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=ce5KbCTfHoA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}", function( data ) {
    var likes = data['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount'];
});
```

This should work. Use jQuery documentation.

Comment: Wonderful, I will try this out and let you know how it goes. Thanks, Dantez.

Comment: You can't just actually do that. Parsed it to an object before you can do that.

Comment: So I'm using this example and it's not returning anything. Aldrin, can you please give me an example on how to parse it to an object and display the results? Please excuse my ignorance on the subject, I have a lot of learning ahead of me. Thanks

Comment: use the `$.parseJSON($yourDataHere);`

Comment: This actually did work without needing the $.parseJSON() function. Thanks all of you, this really helped.